# Use table column header in VBA code for userform

Tags: excel, vba, tablecolumn

I have built a table with a lot of columns. I would like to create a user form to show a majority of the information in the columns so I can hide the columns in the spreadsheet so there isn't so much to look at. A lot of columns can be overwhelming when looking at it. I know some of the most popular ways to write VBA so that data in the user form makes it into the table. However I noticed that if I ever needed to add a column I then have to edit the vba code to make sure the data still goes in the correct cells.

So my question is this. Is there a way to write the code using the table column headers so the code uses the header label as a point of reference instead of the column number?

Comment: Yes. You can refer to the cell of the column headers "Table1[[#Headers],[Column1]]" and "Table1[[#Headers],[Column2]]" so on  as  Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Column1]]") and Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Column2]]")

Comment: Naresh. Thanks for the tip. Ill give it a shot!

Comment: Thanks to you for asking... I too didn't know :)